# delete rows with character in cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array, strncmp

I need some basic help. I have a cell array:

1. TITLE 13122423
2. NAME Bob
3. PROVIDER James

and many more rows with text...

44. 234  456  234  345
45. 324  346  234  345
46. 344  454  462  435

and many MANY (>4000) more with only numbers

4100. text
4101. text

and more text and mixed entries

Now what I want is to delete all the rows where the first column contain a character, and end up with only those rows containing numbers. Row 44 - 46 in this example.

I tried to use

rawdataTruncated(strncmp(rawdataTruncated(:, 1), 'A', 1), :) = [];

but then i need to go throught the whole alphabet, right?

Comment: Have you looked at using "startsWith"?

Comment: What are the actual data types of your cells? Are they all char/string arrays or are they mixed data types?

Comment: My data be like this: C = {'TITLE' '13122423'; '3234' '13122423'; 'The end' '13122423'} where I want to delete the entire row which contain any char/string. The outcome would be out= { '3234' '13122423'}

Comment: So every entry in your cell array is a string?

Comment: @J.Birch: We need a bit more clarity on your data, since your post and comment seem to disagree a bit. Does your cell array contain **only** strings (with letters and numbers in them), or does it also contain actual numeric values (**not** strings)? Does any row containing a string with letters (in either column) need to be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given data of the form:

```
C = {'FIRSTX'   '350.0000' ''        ''        ; ...
     '350.0000' '0.226885' '254.409' '0.755055'; ...
     '349.9500' '0.214335' '254.41'  '0.755073'; ...
     '250.0000' 'LASTX'    ''        ''        };
```

You can remove any row that has character strings containing letters using [`isstrprop`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isstrprop.html), [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), and [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) like so:

```
index = ~any(cellfun(@any, isstrprop(C, 'alpha')), 2);
C = C(index, :)

C =
  2×4 cell array

    '350.0000'    '0.226885'    '254.409'    '0.755055'
    '349.9500'    '0.214335'    '254.41'     '0.755073'
```

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. My real data is like this C = { 'FIRSTX' '350.0000' '' '' ; '350.0000' '0.226885' '254.409' '0.755055' ; '349.9500' '0.214335'   '254.41' '0.755073' ; '250.0000' 'LASTX'  ''  ''} . I want to delete the entire row which contain any char/string in any of the columns. In this case I would end up with : out= {'350.0000' '0.226885' '254.409' '0.755055' ; '349.9500' '0.214335'   '254.41' '0.755073'}.

Comment: @J.Birch: Okay, I think that sounds clearer, and I've updated my answer accordingly. For clarity, you should edit your question so it describe the data as you have done in this comment.

Comment: That is awesome gnovice. Thanks a lot